# Wireless drops on HP ENVY dv6 with RT3290 wireless, worked without problem prior to upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, can it be fixed?

Tags: wireless, 13.10, hp

I have a HP ENVY dv6 Notebook PC with an AMD A10 quad core and RT3290 wireless.  Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, the wireless connects, but then drops after a few minutes or longer, whether or not I am running openconnect to get through a VPN.  If I attempt to run a remote X client (e.g. remote xterm) it drops.  If I don't run an X client, it disconnects after a while, requiring a reload of the driver and reconnect.

Wireless info...

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 68:94:23:a7:09:cb
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.11.0-12-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.1.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:55 memory:f0210000-f021ffff
```

I have successfully built and installed the MediaTek driver with no luck on connecting, then the system hangs on reboot and I have to recover/undo the changes to boot successfully.

---

2013/11/10 update...

I discovered that running a popular speed test on the web is a quick way to get the wireless to disconnect during the upload portion of the test.

Using the aforementioned method to reproduce the problem, I have installed and tested the [Linux Kernel 3.12 Release as documented here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/linux-kernel-3-12-released-install-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/) on my Ubuntu 13.10 system and thus far I have not see the problem with wireless disconnecting again...

Answer (score 1):

Installation of the kernel update on Ubuntu 13.10 with 4 simple commands as documented in [Linux Kernel 3.12 Released, Install it in Ubuntu...](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/linux-kernel-3-12-released-install-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/) appears to fix the RT3290 wireless problem for now.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200-generic_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_i386.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy/linux-image-3.12.0-031200-generic_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.12.0-*.deb linux-image-3.12.0-*.deb
```

11/14 Update - Been running for days on the 3.12 kernel and have not had a single wireless problem!